# Should this embedded software development question have been closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[How different is the Arduino language than Atmel Studio language?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84593/how-different-is-the-arduino-language-than-atmel-studio-language)

The close reason is "does not appear to be about electronics design within the scope defined in the help center", but the text in the help center suggests questions about development of software for embedded systems is on-topic, so should this have been closed or not?

Comment: With the same reasoning I could ask photoshop questions here because I do my soldermask layouts with photoshop

Comment: @PlasmaHH I don't think so, no.  Atmel Studio and Arduino IDE are both *primarily* designed for developing embedded systems, but Photoshop is not *primarily* designed for producing layouts.

Comment: If it were posted today, that question would be migrated to Arduino.SE .  Back in 2013, the Arduino.SE haven't been established yet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it was a fine close.  It would not have been a great candidate for migration, as it wasn't a very good question in the first place.